# mysql 5.6 GTID replication 'Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log'

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.6, mysqladmin

I Checked SHOW SLAVE STATUS   error  is "'Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log: ''The slave is connecting using CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_AUTO_POSITION = 1, but the master has purged binary logs containing GTIDs that the slave requires.''

i am suspecting it happens because of  master old binary  log (7 days before) deleted form master as we  are  using  expire_logs_days=7 option and slave still looking  for this old binary  log for  some GTID reference to replicate   with  master.

I tried following  link  solution ,

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/02/08/how-to-createrestore-a-slave-using-gtid-replication-in-mysql-5-6/

but  it still not  working.

Note :using  mysql  5.6.15

Now only  option for me to  re-create  slave   by  taking  mysqldump from master.

Is there any other option if  we can start replication without recreating  new slave.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you have any idea how long replication has been broken for the slave?

Comment: around  1 hour,before replication break it  was in sync with  master  and replicating  binary  log  available on master.

Comment: If you have backup of these bin logs then only you can otherwise only option is to re create slave.